# "Have been + verb-ing" vs. "have + past participle"

Tags: present-perfect

What's the difference between the following constructions of present perfect:

> I've been waiting for you for seven years.
>
> I've waited for you for seven years.

Googling yields no satisfying results. I also asked a native speaker and the one wasn't sure about the difference between the two, so I would like to know if there is any.

Comment: related: [Went to vs have been to](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69077/went-to-vs-have-been-to)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use "have been —ing"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19065/how-to-use-have-been-ing)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Present perfect for past action with present effect](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57869/present-perfect-for-past-action-with-present-effect)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In "I've been waiting for you for seven years" the focus is on the act of waiting. Maybe you want to emphasise how long seven years is, or make the listener understand how patient you have been.

In "I've waited for you for seven years" the focus is on the result of the wait. Now, perhaps you want to emphasis that the wait is over, or you are unwilling to wait any longer, or you are really angry now.

[This gives](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv67.shtml) a quick overview.

Comment: The Have Been V+ing can actually focus on the activity, and it doesn't matter whether it has been finished or not. But with the Have P.P., how exactly do you propose to emphasize results when the action isn't completed? Have P.P. normally answers questions like: How many, How many times etc.

Comment: I have shown you numerous ways to talk about results of uncompleted actions (and I haven't finished - another PPS for uncompleted action). In what way is "She has written 7 novels, and another one is due next year" wrong. If you are going to say my examples are wrong, you really should say why.

Comment: Of course any Have P.P. example with the added "but still..." will mean unfinished - a child can see what you're doing there. Can't you just make your examples with a Have P.P. and Have Been V+ing Verb and a full stop, then compare? So you'll finally see clearer? Your explanation is backwards from how most grammar books do it. As a matter of fact, your example i.e. "She has written 7 novels" is the prototypical example in grammar that ILLUSTRATES the COMPLETION of the action. How is it still my responsibility to clarify this basic point?

Answer (score 2):

I am unaware of any difference between “I’ve been waiting for you” and “I have waited for you”. I would use these two completely interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "*Have Been + Past Participle*," which is the **Present Perfect Passive**.

It's actually "*Have Been V+ing*" also known as the **Present Perfect Progressive** or Present Perfect Continuous.

It is used for an activity that started in the past and still continues to the present.

On the other hand, the Present Perfect Simple (Have P.P.) is used for completed actions.

Simple examples would be:

> **Ex.** Oh, are you ever gonna come back? **I've been waiting** for you for seven years!

while

> **Ex.** I'm sorry. You're too late. **I've waited** for you for seven years and now I'm a married woman.

Comment: Wouldn't plain old past simple " I'm sorry. You're too late. *I waited* for you for seven years and now I'm a married woman" be a better sentence?  Present Perfect Simple is for an action until now, but it does not have to be completed. "I have ridden horses for 7 years" doesn't mean I no longer ride horses. That would be "I rode horses for 7 years".

Comment: I can't understand you, @RoaringFish. In the link that you recommended to the OP, these points are very clearly expressed: (1) Whether teaching or learning the present perfect, it is often useful to present the two verb aspects in a contrastive way.  (2) Both the present perfect simple and the present perfect continuous relate a past action to the present, but the present perfect simple suggests a completed action and focuses more on achievements and results.

Comment: (3) When we use the present perfect continuous, however, there is usually a suggestion that the activity is not yet completed, or we wish to emphasise the length of time it has lasted or stress the continuous, on-going nature of the activity.

Comment: A suggestion is not a grammatical rules, as you state("Present Perfect Simple (Have P.P.) is used for completed actions"). It is a suggestion, nothing more. It is a suggestion because, as I said in my post, PPS focusses on the result, and a result usually implies completion - but not always. I have given you loads of examples of PPS for actions that are not complete. Which one of my examples is wrong? "J.K. Rowling has written seven novels" Has J.K. Rowling stopped writing? Is her writing action completed?

Comment: Perhaps what you should consider is how you're gonna prepare the OP to grasp all of these things. This is why (from your link): "Whether teaching or learning the present perfect, it is often useful to present the two verb aspects in a contrastive way." You chose your own suggestion/ focus to follow and people chose theirs. But it would seem that, from your comments, you're contradicting your own source

Comment: Let me make the proper pair of examples for you: (1) J.K. Rowling has been writing novels since 1997. (2) In fifteen years, she has written seven best sellers. I patterned these sentences from the very link that you provided

Answer (score 0):

To describe an action that has started in the past and is still continuing, you would say it in present perfect continuous tense. If the action has ended, you would say it in present perfect tense.

If your wait started seven years ago but you still are waiting, then you would say, “I have been waiting for seven years.” If you waited for seven years and you are done waiting and you are moving on now, you would say, “I have waited for seven years.”

Comment: "He has lived in Paris for six years, and has no plans to leave" ~ Present perfect simple, but the action has not ended.

Comment: That's because the verb "live" can use both Have P.P. and Have Been V+ing to mean continuing action

Comment: "He has driven his car 3000 miles, and he has 3000 more to go"; "He has woken up at 8 o'clock every morning for 20 years, and he has no plans to wake up at any other time"; "He has drunk beer since he was 16, and always will"; "So far this week, I have seen three movies, and there is another one tomorrow" ~ all present perfect simple, and still not completed actions.

Comment: I can't understand you, @RoaringFish. In the link that you recommended to the OP, these points are very clearly expressed: (1) Whether teaching or learning the present perfect, it is often useful to present the two verb aspects in a contrastive way. (2) Both the present perfect simple and the present perfect continuous relate a past action to the present, but the present perfect simple suggests a completed action and focuses more on achievements and results.

Comment: Let me make the proper pair of examples for you: (1) In fifteen years, J.K.Rowling has written seven best sellers (full stop) (2) She has been writing novels since 1997. I patterned these sentences from the very link that you provided

Comment: Well done, you used PPC. You can do that if, as I said, you want to focus on the activity. In no way does that mean my sentences, using PPS for uncompleted actions, are wrong. If you think my examples are wrong, tell me why.

Comment: Of course any Have P.P. example with the added "but still..." will be unfinished - a child can see what you're doing there. Can't you just make your examples with a Have P.P. and Have Been V+ing Verb and a full stop, then compare? So you'll finally see clearer? Your explanation is backwards from how most grammar books do it. As a matter of fact, your example i.e. "She has written 7 novels" is the prototypical example in grammar that illustrates the COMPLETION of the action.

Comment: Ask yourself why my examples are correct - it is because PPS does not mean the action is finished. If your grammar books are telling you that "she has written 7 novels" means she is dead and will never write again, throw them away and buy some proper ones. I sincerely hope you are not telling students that. "She *wrote* 7 novels" means she will never write again; "she has written" means she may write again. What you are trying to say is that PPS and past simple are the same thing, when they are not.

Comment: Here are some helpful links to help you get straight on this one: ["He’s written 16 books." ~ He started writing books at some time in the past. So far, he has written 16 books. *He may write more books*.](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/present-perfect-simple-and-present-perfect-continuous). My italics. [1. Betty taught for ten years. (simple past), 2. Betty has taught for ten years. (present perfect). The implication in (1) is that Betty has retired; in (2), *that she is still teaching*.](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/601/). Again my italics.

Comment: Look here, @Roaringfish. I know for a fact that the Present Perfect CAN mean unfinished action. But most definitely NOT in the way you are trying to demonstrate it. I am the last person to say that the Have PP and the Past Simple are the same thing. Don't start putting words in my mouth ("she is dead and will never write again") and don't you EVER talk to me about how I teach my students. Don't you EVER criticize the books I read if you don't want me to criticize where you get your ideas from. You don't have the right.

Comment: "On the other hand, the Present Perfect Simple (Have P.P.) is used for completed actions" and "As a matter of fact, your example i.e. "She has written 7 novels" is the prototypical example in grammar that illustrates the COMPLETION of the action."  ~  Your words? Or not?

Comment: Quote no. 1 taken out of context. Quote no. 2 ABSOLUTELY my words. @RoaringFish, I'm a bit tired of talking about the same things, can we just end this thread?